# Conflict between config variables

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5, queue

I have five instant of laravel in my server with different nginx config works fine

Also i used redis queue to send messages and in production env i cached env variable with php artisan `config:cache` and i used `config('app.url')` instead of `env(app.url)`

But when i want to send messages with queue from project1 ,in message shows some variable from project 4 , and when i run `php artisan config:clear` works fine

But i don't want to use .env variable directly i want to use variable in production env with cached config

I also used below commands , but does not work:

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan route:clear
 php artisan queue:restart
 composer dump-autoload
 composer dump-autoload -o
 php artisan optimize
```

This is my .env file :

```
  APP_ENV=produnction
  APP_DEBUG=true

  APP_URL=http://name.com/api/v1.0

  APP_DOMAIN=project1
  APP_NAME_FA=project1
  APP_NAME_EN=project1
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: can you post the `.env` file? you could use different names for variables , `PROJECT1_URL` etc.

Comment: there is no way without changing variables?

Comment: minor fix is `production` not `produnction`

Comment: can i add prefix to variables? i mean still use `config('app.url')` in projects but when i added prefix i use `config(prefix.app.url)` .. do you think this solves the problem؟

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to change , you may host multiple domains with one Laravel application but the `.env` will be one per application, that's why you get the same value.

You can try creating multiple Laravel application for each project with their own configuration `.env`

or

use one Laravel application handling multiple domains and use different variable names for each project in one `.env`.

Another way to solve this is creating an custom configuration file under config directory and place whatever you want in there and use `config` helper.

-update

be careful when you use `env` and when you use `config` .. `env()` will look into `.env` first and config will look into config directory .

ex. `env('PREFIX_APP_URL')` will look into `.env` for `PREFIX_APP_URL`

while `config('prefix.app.url')` will look into config directory file for an nested array for `prefix` file for an array

```
return array(
 'app'=>array(
    'url'=>'...value..'
 )
)
```

Comment: can i add prefix to variables? i mean still use `config('app.url')` in projects but when i added prefix i use `config(prefix.app.url)` .. do you think this solves the problem؟

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear 

php artisan config:cache
```

If you are using the config:cache command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.

If you are calling env from within your application, it is strongly recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration files and call env from that location instead, allowing you to convert your env calls to config calls.

Read whole thread over https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21727